# Google Dictionary in Ubuntu

Tags: google, dictionary

Is it possible to install Google Dictionary Extension / Plugin in Entire Ubuntu OS as well as in Mozilla?

[Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en) is an example extension for Google Dictionary for the Chrome web browser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is not os related; its browser related and  you can use other addons in firefox but if you can't live without that extension then install google chrome ( in Ubuntu) or better install chromium ( which is the base of chrome ) and install that extension in chromium(or chrome) from chrome web store

Use the following terminal command to install chromium

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

to install google chrome download the .deb file and install